# Using Python Slice?

Tags: python

How Python Slice work, Need explanation

I have name of datasets, like : annmly_spei06_2001.shp, annmly_spei06_2002.shp...........

Below slicing capturing the whole data name, but i want only year vale from input data to assign as a name of output raster

```
tifname = fc[:-4]
IDW_OUT= os.path.join(out_folder, '{0}.tif'.format(tifname))
```

How to capture  only year value from input data, for output raster name?

Comment: This is a pure Python question that should be researched at [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to learn more about how slice works then the following will help you with that:

[Slicing in Python](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/)

So, in essence what you are doing is getting a substring and this is dead simple in Python using the slice method, just remember that the slice is:

```
array[start:end]
```

So it is saying from the array `start` at a position and then `end` at the next position. In your example it is returning the whole dataset name because you have omitted the `start` value. Python takes that to mean take the first element of the array. The `end` value of `-4` means stop fetching elements 5 back from the last. To get what you are after you need to specify the start position too. Assuming you are after the year element then you just need to tweak your line:

```
tifname = fc[-8:-4]
```

So the `-8` will count back from the end of the string which will pick up the start of a 4 digit date and the `-4` will ignore the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

You should find everything you need to solve this here:

http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/

In your case, you need to reference a slice between two positions, both which should be referenced from the end of the string (as opposed to the beginning).

```
tifname=fc[-8:-4]
```

should work, which you can read as "a slice that begins 8 characters before the end of the string, and ends 4 characters before the end of the string".